# Trying to determine why Chrome (Win 7 64) with many tabs open is spinning. Is there a browser/OS/ISP test for multiple connection throughput?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, home-networking

I am running Chrome on Win 7 64 on a 3 year old machine.

Often when "many" tabs are open (more than 5, less than 20), Chrome will spin. Seemingly doing nothing. Pages appearing to wait for more network input. And yet, I am on a DSL line that netspeed shows as usually supporting about 50Mbps down.

It makes me wonder if my machine is borked, or my router, or the ISP, when it comes to handling the hundreds of open connections involved in trying to load multiple pages.

Are there any tests, analogous to say www.speedtest.net, that tests a browsers ability to service multiple connections, or the OS, or the router, or the ISP?

Comment: It sounds like a DNS problem. Try using Google's DNS (8.8.8.8) or OpenDNS(208.67.222.222). Also try [turning off Auto Detect Proxy](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/106010?hl=en) in Chrome settings

Comment: Thanks, auto detect proxy was in fact off, and I have reset my dhcp server to serve up google's dns and opendns.

Comment: Do you get the same issue when using a different browser?